# Android application framework

Tags: android-framework

I'm new to android app development. I've looking to build a traditional database driven app in which the app will store/retrieve data from a local data store.  Can anyone help me get started with a framework   or " Can someone point me to sample apps that do this

Answer (score 0):

Visit the developer site for Android application development.

[Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Comment: I am not aware about drupal. Can't help you in that.